# django: ошибка "Reverse for ... not found."

Tags: python, django, веб-программирование

Сама ошибка выглядит так:

> Reverse for 'system' with keyword arguments '{'pk': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['/systems/(?P[0-9]+)/$']

содержимое models.py:

```
class Systems(models.Model):
   name= models.CharField(max_length=1000)
   link1 = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
   ver1 = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
   buttontext = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
   offweb= models.CharField(max_length=1000)
```

содержимое urls.py:

```
path('/systems/<int:pk>/', views.system_detail, name='system'),
path('/systems', views.system_list, name='systems'),
```

содержимое viwes.py:

```
def system_list(request):
    text = Systems.objects
    return render(request, 'systems.html', {'text': text})

def system_detail(request, pk):
    text = get_object_or_404(Systems, pk=pk)
    return render(request, 'system.html', {'text': text})
```

содержимое systems.html:

```
<a href="{% url 'system' pk=text.pk %}" class="gradient-button">{{systems.buttontext}}</a>
```

ошибка возникает при вызове systems.html

спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Предположу, что у вас опечатка вот здесь

```py
# views.py
def system_detail(request, pl): # думается мне, что здесь должно быть pk вместо pl
....
```

Возможно, так же у вас путаница с файлами `systems.html` и `system.html`.

```py
def system_list(request):
    text = Systems.objects.all() # вот здесь тоже опечатка
    return render(request, 'systems.html', {'text': text})
```

Comment: Спасибо,исправил. Но ничего не изменилось.

Comment: @spfxd ошибка та же?

Comment: Да, ничего не изменилось

Comment: @spfxd Тут только гадать( не достаточно информации. Как организованы urls.py? у вас один файл должен быть основной и второй в приложении. Или вы используете один? используете ли вы namespaces для urlов приложения и так далее....